# Track page load event of GA for Single page application on every url change

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I have used GTM and GA both in my single page application.
For tracking pageview on every url change i have written tag and trigger in the GTM and able to track url in GA on every URL change.
but how to track page load event on every url change ? this is my big question.
As per i know we only track url and send pageview on everypage load in website using normal ga actions.

```
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

What should i do for tracking page load event in gtm or ga for SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SPA, you'd want to configure your GTM triggers differently. The standard "All pages" trigger fires on all page loads, if you configured it this way for your SPA, and your SPA is at example.com/myapp then you'll see a pageview to that URL in GA when the SPA loads.

Once the SPA is loaded, subsequent routing/screen changes won't trigger this GA tag in GTM again.

What I found most versatile is to use [custom events](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679219?hl=en) and [datalayer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide) to manage these during routing.

Example, in your SPA when routing to a new screen you can push the following to the datalyer:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'my-page-title': 'My App - Screen 1',
    'my-page-path': '/my-screen-1',
    'event': 'my-screen-load'});
```

You can replace the 'My App - Screen 1' and '/my-screen-1' with variables to make it dynamic, but that's more part of your SPA design and totally up to you if you want it dynamic or static.

When you have done that, in GTM, you will set up 2 variables, 1 trigger and 1 GA tag:

**Variables :** 
You'll create a "Data Layer Variable" in GTM, referencing the "my-page-path" key in the datalyer object. Like so:
[image]
I like to set a default value for error checking, just in case someone triggered this event and didn't provide a value for it in the datalyer and it wasn't already set, the default value will catch that. Do the same for the 'my-page-title' key.

**Trigger**
Create a 'Custom Event' trigger in GTM, reference the 'my-screen-load' event, make sure you select "all custom events" for "this trigger fires on" like so:
[image]

**GA Tag**
Create a new Google Analytics tag in GTM. Put in the correct settings (ID or settings variable). Then under "more settings -> fields to set" add in "page" and "title" as two fields to set and use the respective GTM variable names. Then add in the trigger we just created. Example:
[image]

This should allow you to track screen views in your SPA.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GTM you can setup your standard GA page view tag with "History Change" trigger to fire virtual page view. "History Change" trigger is used exactly for single page applications as you described.

In GTM, click on your GA tag and go to triggers -> New -> Trigger Configuration -> History Change

You can read more about it on GTM support page [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679322?hl=en).